# How to prevent against Apache server hacking attempts

Tags: linux, apache, security, mod-wsgi

I started up an apache server on a raspberry pi to learn to build python servers and have noticed unsuccessful attempts to locate phpmyadmin files. I figure this is a good a time as any to start learning about security... Upon looking up on the subject I saw some advocating against adding too much extra security because it might inspire some hackers to dig further... I don't want my linux box to be someone's playgroud, but I do want to learn security. Where do I start?

Comment: Modern cryptography is based on abstract algebra.

Comment: Is that why you became a DJ?

Comment: If not using PHP, then simply ensure you don't install the Apache module for it as a start. Bigger question is why your Raspberry Pi was exposed to a public network in the first place if you are getting requests like that. If this is supposed to only be in your own home network, you should not see such requests unless something in your home network has already been compromised.